# Detect visibility changes of any visual components on a form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is it possible to get an event fired whenever any visual component on a Delphi form changes its visibility status, i.e. when it becomes visible or invisible?
I could write a timer with e.g. 10 ms to check this, but it would be very cumbersome. Isn't there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: do you want to do this for any type of control? Also, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Generally for a single control, but possibly also for several controls (which includes for several types of controls). For debugging purposes.

Comment: You could replace the window procedure. Use the WindowProc property. Listen for CM_VISIBLECHANGED. I think.

Comment: Keep a list of *all* controls and their visibility states at all times in a list. Override `AlignControls` on the form. Whenever it's hit, iterate the list for a *possible* state change. I'm not really suggesting this of course.